# Identity values not re-starting from 1 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

For ID column Value, first time when i run the query it is counting from 1 to 500..

Next time when i run the console once again and execute the query, my id Value is not counting from 1, It is counting from 501 to 1000.(previously where it is stopped) and incrementing thereafter...

Comment: Ah yes, I can picture it so well</sarcasm>. Perhaps if you actually posted some code (or a sample that exhibits the same behaviour), we might be able to help you.

Comment: Eg: ID 1 2 3 .. n
next time when i run the java console and execute the query i am getting the ID value as n n+1 n+2 and so on..

Comment: But i want it from the start like 1 2 3 and so on

Comment: This is by design with an `IDENTITY` column.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean you have a table with an autonumber column, that you have populated and then subsequently deleted from, one way is to re-seed the table with [`DBCC CHECKIDENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx)

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ("MySchema.MyTable", RESEED, 1);
GO
```

Comment: Actually i am not using any query to create the table...

Comment: That comment (without context) makes no sense I'm afraid

Comment: i am just setting the ID column properties (seed and Increment value to 1 respectively). But there is no Reseed options in that..

Comment: Run the above code, and the table will be reseeded...

Comment: what is "MySchema.MyTable"?? is it table name ???

Comment: Oh many tanx mitch wheat.. now its working perfectly

Comment: If this answer helped you, don't forget to accept it as the answer.